# jsPDF generate pdf with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, plugins, jspdf

I use these version for jspdf:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

I have big div on my page , example of it is:

```
<div id="template_invoice">
<div id="first_head">
    <div id="logo_invoice" class="has-65">
        <img src="" width="280px">
    </div>
    <div id="main_header_info" class="has-35">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
    <div id="second_head">
        <div id="lead_address" class="has-65">
            <span id="lead_name"></span><br>
            <span id="lead_street"></span><br>
            <span id="lead_postcode_city"></span><br>
        </div>
         <div id="lead_invoice_info" class="has-35">
            <div class="span_padding_invoice">
            <span class="invoice_main_span">Rechnungs-Nr.</span>
            <span id="lead_rechnungs_nr" class="right-clmn-span"></span>
            <br>
          ...
                </div>
            <div class="span_padding_invoice lead_total_container">
                <span class="invoice_main_span total_bold">Total</span>
                <span id="lead_total" class="right-clmn-span"></span>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content_invoice">
 <div id="rechnung_div">
            <h1>Rechnung</h1>
            <p>Rechnungs-Nr. <span id="rechnung_nr"></span> / Kunden-Nr. <span id="kunder_nr"></span> </p>
        </div>
        <table id="product_invoice_table" width="100%">
                <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="55%">Produkt</th>
                <th width="15%">Menge</th>
                <th width="15%">Preis / Einheit</th>
                <th width="15%">Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
    <div id="footer_invoice">
    </div>
</div>
```

So I generate pdf file using below code:

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

doc.addHTML($('#template_invoice')[0], function () { var pdf = doc.output('blob'); .... });
```

All works fine, but if height of cotent is larger then page there are not second,third.. other pages.
I tried use pagesplit:true, but it works wrong, there are not right font,css and instead of 2 pages I get 4 pages with wrong css.

I need any help to solve this problem, how can I set multiple page for my div?

Thanks very much for help!

Now I get such pdf with pagesplt flag:
http://clip2net.com/s/3ObsVZc

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose a page format that is close enough to what you want when creating the pdf like so. try the below line when you generating file

```
var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", "letter");
```

Comment: ok apply this line                                                                                                
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

Comment: And also read this documentation you will get you answer.
https://www.sitepoint.com/generating-pdfs-from-web-pages-on-the-fly-with-jspdf/

Comment: I get http://clip2net.com/s/3ObvkrZ
it is wrong css  and font for my page